# Detect which phone number is sms capable

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible to determine whether a phone number is SMS capable or not, i.e. it is a mobile number?  I realize that the user can set the type of number when editing the contact, but I'm looking for something authoritative.

Thanks.

Comment: any solution for that thread?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [libphonenumber](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/&ei=keZdUsn1K6fO0QWll4DAAQ&usg=AFQjCNHAyySkD3HtEK_ESX-BpMeuTlssew&sig2=xxkCEgwKcHOAaaheO2N-Qg&bvm=bv.54176721,d.d2k) for determine if one number is mobile or not, but in some countries ( like USA ) there's no distinction between mobile numbers and landline numbers.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but that doesn't really help.  Somehow my phone's default SMS app seems to know which number is mobile regardless of what type I set it to in the contacts app.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ready to pay then there are two websites I know which can provide you API to lookup whether a phone number is cell phone or landline using NPA and the NXX information (only for US and Canada I think so).

I don't think they'll be smart enough to tell you whether a number is ported from landline to mobile or not. But that becomes unusual case for current market scenario.

1) [Strikeiron](http://www.strikeiron.com/product-list/phone/phone-number-validation/)

2) [SearchBug](http://www.searchbug.com/)

You haven't mentioned whether you want a system based on US or entire world. So I assumed only US while answering.

I hope this will help little bit.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there was some other way to know.  I guess there isn't, which is fine.  I'm in the same boat as everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

There are providers like [Trestle](https://trestleiq.com/) that provide whether the number if ported and currently it is Landline/Mobile/Fixed or Non Fixed VOIP, etc. That should help determine if the number is SMS Enabled, etc.